# JQuery: открыть закрыть блок

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста есть такой скрипт.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropw_dawnd_text").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr("id");
$("#dropwdanw_friends"+I).slideToggle(0);
$(this).toggleClass("active");
return false;
 });
});
```

Например есть два блока, при клике открываются два блока, как сделать что бы открывался один блок, а при клике на второй открывался второй, а первый бы закрывался.

Comment: лучше всего не toggleClass тут делать а 

    $(".dropw_dawnd_text").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

так - потому что не надо хранить состояние логики в dom.

Answer (score 2):

Привет я **не** верно понял ворпос. 
Во первых #dropwdanw_friends1, #dropwdanw_friends2 ... должны добавить какой то класс , на пр. **toggle-dropdown** и только после этого ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropw_dawnd_text").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
    var element = $(this);
    //Закрываем все блоки
    $(".toggle-dropdown").removeClass('active');
    //Открываем ту которая нам нужна 
    element.addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Comment: зачем each ? ненужен, это то-же самое что

 $("Your_block_id_or_class").toggleClass("active");